# Pointers for monitoring drupal 6 site needed, difference in server aw stats and the core "statistics" data

Tags: seo, drupal-6

The IP addresses logged in by the Drupal 6 core "Statistics" module are not being displayed by the AW statistics displayed by my hosting server (hostgator). I am not able to comprehend why and which statistics are more reliable ? Also I would request some light to be shed on the best practices to monitor a Drupal 6 website. Thanks for your help people.

Answer (score 0):

the best free analytics packages are google analytics and piwik. i personally would go for piwik.

Heres a good [A vs B](http://groupmagnet.blogspot.com/2009/01/piwik-vs-google-analytics.html)

Also worth checking out the [goal tracking](http://piwik.org/docs/javascript-tracking/) if thats what you need as i believe this is something thats missed out of the 1st link - maybe this was done before goal tracking was integrated

As for the mentions of  funnels analysis, yes piwik might not do that yet, but its on the roadmap. Its worth factoring this into your plans - do you want to track specific the funnels of customers to conversion? e.g. the % of x people and the route they took to purchase?

Another [A vs B](http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/000534)

Comment: Hi Ke .. thanks for your reply .Just curious  are there any particular reasons why you find piwik better than google analytics ? What about BAWSTATS module ?

Comment: i like piwik more than GA because with piwik the source code sits on your server. last time i looked it seems as though piwik has come a long way (similar to ga) with goal tracking etc but there might be a few things missing. i guess the question to ask are do you want easy setup? and dont mind google having all your data? if so GA might be right, if not then Piwik might do. Me personally, i dont like giving away all that data to google, especially when I want my sites to rank highly while not giving too much away - check the terms and conditions, Google can use the data how they want to.